# Degrees of factors of polynomial $f(x)=x^q-(ax^2+bx+c)\in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, finite-fields, factorization

I’m facing the problem of factoring polynomials of type $f(x)=x^q-(ax^2+bx+c)\in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ and the degrees of factors seem to be quite special. For example, according to my experimental results done by [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/), there are only 24 kinds of factorizations of different degrees appearing when I factor 100 random such polynomials in $F_{81}[x]$ and factors of degrees {5, 20, 56} appear 5 times, factors of degrees {1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 25, 32} appear 5 times, factors of degrees {1, 1, 2, 3, 8 ,66} appear 8 times, … . What is the cause of this phenomenon? There are papers concerning the factorization of $f(x)=x^q-(bx+c)\in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ like http://dml.cz/dmlcz/126360, but I cannot find a suitable one for my type.

Comment: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804860/degrees-of-factors-of-polynomial-fx-xq-ax2bxc-in-mathbbf-qx)--Here is the link to the same question I pasted to math.stackexchange 1 minute ago because I cannot tell the difference between the two sites. However, I haven't get any solutions or hints yet.

Comment: To find out the difference, read the FAQ for the sites. We prefer (vey much) that you do not post on both sites at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a special case of thm 2.3 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0625  (version 3, I've just updated it, it has a different number in version 2) that the factorization pattern of polynomials $x^q-(ax^2+bx+c)$ distributes the same as random permutation in $S_n$ (unless $q$ is a power of $2$). In fact this theorem deals with $h(x) + (ax^2+bx+c)$, uniformly on $h$ of fixed degrees.

In the case $x^{p^2} - (bx+c)$, for example, the factorization is related to cycle structure of permutations in the group of transformations of the affine line over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, while in $x^{p^2+1}-(bx+c)$ it is related to the transformations of the projective line. See last section in the ms.

Comment: Thanks and I think the result in the paper you provide is just what I am looking for, although the details in your proof are far beyond my knowledge and understanding since I am not a student majoring math. In fact, the question I ask comes from the heuristic assumptions on some algorithms in several recent papers like http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/400 and http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/095.

Comment: Concretely, they have an assumption on the existence of degree-$k$ irreducible factors of polynomials of type $h_1(x)x^q-h_0(x)$ when the degrees of $h_1(x)$ and $h_0(x)$ are small constants like 2 or 3 for any $k\leq q$ (actually the coefficients should be in $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ in my question, but they do have similarity). The assumption can be verified by experiments (by both the authors and me) but cannot be proved theoretically. And I think your answer can give the good explanation.

Comment: Can you tell me what the value/range of $c(k)$ is in your thm 2.3? That is important for me to give the estimation of the probability of degree-$k$ factor's appearance and I cannot find this in the references. Due to my experimental results (again, by Magma), the two distributions are still different. So I have to make sure whether the $q$ I use is too small.

Comment: We didn't calculate the error term explicitly in terms of $k$, but it should be polynomial in $k!$ (since it is so bad, we haven't bothered to explicitly compute it). The point is that the constant in this method comes from the extension corresponding to the Galois group which is the full symmetric group (of order $k!$)

Comment: Is the result in [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X71900382) which also appears as Thm 3.86 in the book Finite Fields by Rudolf Lidl, Harald Niederreiter the special case of $m=1$ of yours?

Comment: Thanks @user51099 I was not aware of this paper.

Answer (score 11):

Actually the factorization patterns don't look all that special:
they feel like the cycle structures of random permutations in
the symmetric group $S_{81}$, unlike the special case $a=0$,
and unlike the (somewhat more interesting) polynomials $x^{q+1}+bx+c$.
The repetitions do require explanation, but the explanation is simply that
the polynomials themselves are repeating: they seem to vary over $q^3$ choices
of $(a,b,c)$, but it's only about $q$ up to translation and scaling.
If $a \neq 0$ then $f(x - b/2a)$ yields a polynomial of the same form 
and with the same $a$, but with $b=0$; and then changing $f(x)$ to
$af(x/a)$ yields an equivalent polynomial with $a=1$ and $b=0$.
When $q = p^f$ with $f>1$ there are also field automorphisms:
$x^q-x-c$ is equivalent to $x^q-x-c^{p^e}$ for each $e=1,2,\ldots,f-1$.
So for $q=81=3^4$ there are only about $q/f \approx 20$ distinct possibilities, 
and in 100 tries you expect to see each pattern appear about $100/20=5$ 
times on average, just as you describe.

Comment: Re: the cycle structures of random permutations, the behavior of at least the short cycles is known asymptotically and may be worth recording here: if $X_k$ is the number of $k$-cycles for $k$ ranging over some numbers sufficiently small compared to $n$ then a random permutation in $S_n$ has the property that the $X_k$ are asymptotically independent Poisson random variables with $\lambda = \frac{1}{k}$. In particular one expects to see $1$ fixed point, a little less than $1$ cycle of length $2$ or $3$, a little less than $1$ cycle of lengths $4$ through $7$, etc.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Is there a small typo in the last sentence of the first paragraph: $x^q-x-c$ should be $x^q-x^2-c$, right?

Comment: Thank you very much and your reply perfectly gives the answer to my question. And one more question: how do all of you (@Noam D. Elkies @QiaochuYuan @LiorBary-Soroker) notice the correspondence between such a polynomial-factoring problem and the cycle structures of random permutations only at a glance? Is there a classic theorem showing that? When I looked for the answer before posting the question here, none the references I can access mention this.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can I use this to give an estimation of the probability of degree-$k$ factor's appearance?

Comment: @user: I read http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/Anatomy.pdf and then I thought about it for a bit. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev's_density_theorem is also relevant. (The permutation that we're assuming is random is Frobenius.) Yes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How about the case of characteristic $p=2$? The number of its factoring patterns are also much less than $q^3$ but the polynomial cannot be written as the simple form above. It is easy to cancel the constant term by translation, however, there are still much less than $q^2$ patterns.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment: Is it easy to cancel the constant term? I didn't think carefully when writing that sentence and find that maybe I took it for granted just now.